# Database driven service configurations - Design or over-Design

Tags: web-services, architecture, windows-services, soa

Very nervous to ask this question but wanted to put this out there and get some feedback on why/why not/why the hell would someone want to do this. 
I have various web services/window service that have various configurations values that usually are stored on their respective configuration files.

I thought it would make sense to have a central service whose sole purpose would be to provide the respective web/window services all the configuration details it would need. The configurations would be stored in a database table and each service would request their respective configuration via single web service.

My question is does this sound like over design, or are there other ideas out there that would achieve pretty much the same thing. I feel that this would centralize the configurations therefore make it easier to manage. Also all services would have to conform to configuration interface that would have a defined property of configuration/value pair (NameValueCollection)

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated it.

[image: Service Topography]

Comment: How does `Web Service [ABC]` get its configuration, if the information required to access the `Configuration Service` is itself in the configuration? Unless you have a massive set of configuration values that are in rapid flux, this seems like a seriously over-engineered solution to me.

Comment: Their respective configuration file would only contain the Configuration Service reference rather then other configuration values.

Comment: It is a architectural style choice and there are no rights and wrongs only successful and less successful choices. As Jonathon Reinhart mentioned unless you have configurations that change a massive amount you are probably over-engineering this. On the other  hand if you do encounter this and it is a problem the solution might work. Just keep in mind that having a database storing the configurations means that you will probably have to put that DB server into a High availability solution. This is extra things that can go wrong and requires more effort and maintenance.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this and you'll still need something to bootstrap Service A,B, and C to tell them where the configuration service is and possibly how to interact with it. One of the nice benefits I've found to this is you now have 1 place to look to see how your services should be running as well as making it easier to do audits of your services configurations by looking at the database or configuration service.